# How many generators needed for Pell-equation-related group

Tags: group-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $d$ be a positive integer which is not a perfect square. We have the norm 
multiplicative group homomorphism, $N:{\mathbb Q}[\sqrt{d}] \to {\mathbb Q}$ defined
by $N(x+y\sqrt{d})=x^2-dy^2$.

It is well-known that the restricted kernel
$\lbrace z\in {\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{d}] \ \big| \ N(z)=1 \rbrace$ is an "infinite cyclic"
group, i.e. it is generated by a single element.

What about the unrestricted kernel 
$\lbrace z\in {\mathbb Q}[\sqrt{d}] \ \big| \ N(z)=1 \rbrace$ ? Is it also finitely
generated, and if so how many generators are needed to generate it ?

Comment: [Hilbert 90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Theorem_90) tells us that the solutions are of the form $z=q/\sigma(q)$ with $q$ ranging over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)^*$ and $\sigma$ is the non-trivial automorphism $\sigma(\sqrt d)=-\sqrt d$. My gut feeling is that the group cannot be finitely generated. If the class number were $h=1$, then using generators of split primes in the role of $q$ seems to lead to independent values for $z$ (even in the group of fractional ideals). I think that a suitable modification of this argument would settle the general case as well.